# Using lea for addition

Tags: c, assembly, x86

The following C code:

```
int sum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
add:
        leal    (%rdi,%rsi), %eax
        ret
```

I've only seen `lea` used to move a memory address from one place to another, but here is seems to be moving a value-sum into `eax`. How does that work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, `lea` is an abbreviation for "*load effective **address***" and therefore it was originally intended to perform address calculations.

However: Does it make any difference if the result of the calculation `rsi+rdi` is an address or some integer number?

For the CPU it does not make any difference!

For this reason you **can** use this instruction instead of `add` if you do not require flags to be set.

The operation `rax=rsi+rdi` can be done using **one** `lea` instruction or using a combination of **two** instructions: `mov` and `add`.

Using only one instruction is typically faster and shorter than using two instructions.

And you can even use the instruction (`leal (%rsi,%rdi),%rax`) to perform an 8-, 16- or 32-bit addition because by performing the operation `rax=rsi+rdi` you implicitly perform the operations `eax=esi+edi`, `ax=si+di` and `al=sil+dil`.

If I understand your code correctly, a 32-bit addition (`eax=esi+edi`) is done by the C code.

Comment: +1 for pointing (aha ha) out that `lea` does not affect the flags register. The ability to interleave simple arithmetic performed by `lea` without affecting things like carry flags, or flags used for flow control, is critical to performance in many cases.